# What's a word for where you were raised but not where you were born?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

For example, Mary was **born** in America but she was **raised** in Canada.

America would be her birthplace/place of birth/home country/native country; what's the word for Canada in this scenario?

Hope this makes sense. Feel free to ask for more details if you need them.

Comment: The word(s) for it are "where you were raised." Not all verbs have corresponding nouns.

Answer (score 1):

There's no word as such.  While America is her "birth country", she might well say that Canada is her "home country".  My mum was born on an Airbase in Leicestershire (evacuee) but she wouldn't say that Leicestershire was "home". "Home country" is the country where you feel at home, and can change.

Other people might be raised in multiple locations. Everybody has one "place of birth", but you could have many places where you were raised. So it would normally be easier to use "Raised in Canada (and ...)" rather than use a noun phrase like "place of birth".

Answer (score 0):

It's common for people to call a place they settled in their "*adopted home*". That is sometimes extended to "*adopted homeland*" to mean an entire country. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adopted) also says that "*adopted country*" is used.

Comment: Perhaps, but if you moved to Canada when you were very young, you probably just think of it as "home".  I'd use "adopted home" for a country that I'd moved to when I was older, not one in which I was raised.  Cambridge says it is a country that you have *chosen* (children don't normally get much choice when their parents decide to emigrate)

Comment: @JamesK Someone else can adopt something on your behalf.